# jQuery on drop is not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something `on drop` using jQuery ui.

However, no matter what I do, the `on drop` is not firing at all.

**the code that I using to make divs dragable and dropable is this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({

        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        stack: '.drag',
        revert: "invalid"


    });

            $("#droppable").droppable({

                drop: function (e, ui) {

                    if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                        ui.helper.remove();

                    x.draggable({

                        //helper: 'original',
                        containment: '#droppable',
                        tolerance: 'fit',
                        stack: '.drag'

                    });

                    x.resizable({
                      animate: true,
                      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

                      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                      handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"
                    });
                    x.appendTo('#droppable');

                }

                }
            });


});
```

And the code for doing something on drop is this:

```
                    $(".drag").on("drop", function(e, ui) {


                    //alert('selected');
                    var srcc=$(this).find('img').attr('src');
                    $('#droppable #thumbs #drag_trans img').attr('src',srcc);



});
```

I can change the `on drop` function to normal `click` or `mouseover events` and the code works fine but when I use `on drop`, it won't work.

Could someone please let me know why the on drop is not firing?

Comment: In order for this to work the `on drop` must be on the `droppable` element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/yvpe015y/). There is no `drop` method available for a `draggable` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for adding an additional `on drop` function. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h0Lk2qLv/1/). You can do your changes within the `drop: function (e, ui) {...}` snippet. Used the following JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var x = null;

    //Make element draggable
    $(".drag").draggable({

        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: 'move',
        tolerance: 'fit',
        stack: '.drag',
        revert: "invalid"


    });

            $("#droppable").droppable({

                drop: function (e, ui) {

                    if ($(ui.draggable).attr('id') != "") {
                        x = ui.helper.clone();
                        ui.helper.remove();

                    x.draggable({

                        //helper: 'original',
                        containment: '#droppable',
                        tolerance: 'fit',
                        stack: '.drag'

                    });

                    x.resizable({
                      animate: true,
                      //aspectRatio: 16 / 9,

                      helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
                      handles: "n, e, s, w, nw, ne, sw,se"
                    });
                    x.appendTo('#droppable');

                }

                }
            });


});
```

Comment: Then you can just change your function to use: `$("#droppable").on("drop", function(e, ui) {...}`

Comment: doing the changes inside the `drop :` function works. but For some reason, it will only return the LAST image. I am trying to do this inside drop: function `var srcc=$('this').find('img').attr('src'); alert(srcc);`. any ideas on that?

Comment: Instead of using `$(this)` can you try using `$(ui.helper)`?